# How to increase the size for /dev/mapper/centos-root without data loss

Tags: centos, migration, partition

I am running a virtual server, and the provider added extra diskspace. However, I need to somehow increase (merge) the existing disk (has data) and the new disk (empty).

how to increase the size for `/dev/mapper/centos-root`?

```
[root]#df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.9G  243M  3.7G   7% /run
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root   98G   83G   16G  85% /
tmpfs                    3.9G  156K  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                497M  168M  330M  34% /boot
tmpfs                    797M     0  797M   0% /run/user/1000

[root]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000997be

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048    41943039    20458496   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3        41943040   209715199    83886080   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 104.7 GB, 104694022144 bytes, 204480512 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

It shows a total of > 200GB, so I do have 100GB extra (unused), so I tried to grow it from the Volume Group (VG), but it indicates there is no free space. So I guess I have to somehow add the free space to the VG first? Just how?

```
[root]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               centos
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               99.50 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25473
  Alloc PE / Size       25473 / 99.50 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               mlGu82-tMEl-EB1I-LdvQ-V5Jz-FmRD-7wMPdk
```

Below you see how the LV is divided (between SWAP and ROOT)m guess that is pretty default.

```
[root]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                E4q3BO-bxxu-Mj8J-nNYJ-ECdR-He20-UqTzHd
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2017-07-12 03:09:26 +0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                2.00 GiB
  Current LE             512
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                fANu3W-nl0g-40rQ-NLSA-I77S-4vXE-Stg2D5
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2017-07-12 03:09:27 +0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                97.50 GiB
  Current LE             24961
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1
```

Only in the CFDISK I can actually see there is free space on the same disk: sda

```
 cfdisk (util-linux 2.23.2)

                              Disk Drive: /dev/sda
                       Size: 214748364800 bytes, 214.7 GB
             Heads: 255   Sectors per Track: 63   Cylinders: 26108

    Name        Flags      Part Type  FS Type          [Label]        Size (MB)
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            Pri/Log   Free Space                           1.05*
    sda1        Boot        Primary   xfs                                524.29*
    sda2                    Primary   LVM2_member                      20949.50*
    sda3                    Primary   LVM2_member                      85899.35*
                            Pri/Log   Free Space                      107374.19*
```

For Filesystems (read somewhere not all support resizing):

```
[root]# lsblk -f
NAME            FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda
├─sda1          xfs               9b1d00b3-24f5-4c0e-b84a-d6d9527d375d   /boot
├─sda2          LVM2_member       4rFgZ8-tAZH-8Mr0-hauE-vz9j-YCV4-3gVl3r
│ ├─centos-swap swap              456e16d8-3c60-46b5-812a-3ae2d54f5bcf   [SWAP]
│ └─centos-root xfs               fa159170-1c29-4387-80c4-d168e2cc64c4   /
└─sda3          LVM2_member       c6CKfP-RP63-F107-qJ7G-0lCC-0CJZ-pOKJ4x
  └─centos-root xfs               fa159170-1c29-4387-80c4-d168e2cc64c4   /
```

Also, the centos-root is referenced in the fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root /                       xfs     defaults        1 1
```

I hope I provided enough info to make a good assessment and I really I hope I can increase the disk without data loss, otherwise I have to find a way to transfer 100GB somewhere, and then delete all, and re-create a bigger disk. I am sure there is an easier way in 2022 :)

Thanks in advance!

PS. I did read similar posts of course, but it puzzled me even more. And I am just afraid to accidently remove the existing data (even though I have a backup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
# resize the last partition to utilize the free disk space
growpart /dev/sda 3
# resize the physical volume to match the partition size
pvresize /dev/sda3
# extend the logical volume to utilize the additional space of the physical volume
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/centos/root
# resize the filesystem to match the size of the logical volume
xfs_growfs /dev/centos/root
```

Comment: Gerald, thank you! I did not even have (or knew) about growpart. Was already googling it before you commented on it. But it worked flawless! So this only works when the disk you want to grow, is the last one (connected to the empty) I assume?

At least I will have dinner at home today :)

Comment: Well, if you want to grow a different partitions you need to move the later partitions first. You could also add more partitions and add them to the LVM instead of resizing the partitions.

Comment: Got it! I think we are good for the next few years with this space. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

go the same problem in my case sda 2,

no growpart yet on my box so i,
yum install cloud-utils-growpart -y
then follow the rest and it works,

when it hit 80%, i start googling on how to fix this. (4months gone)
till its 98%, when i found this solution..
you save me a lot of time, Thank you!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/546324)